# stripping strings from "string1234"

Tags: python, string, numbers, strip

I'm new to python and I would like to use this beautiful language in my research of data mining.
I got a large data file in hands now and unfortunately the samples identities are defined as strings attached to numbers, something like this:

A, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3
0.2,0.456,0.7,1.01,0.91,0.11,0.31

In order for me to build a useful classifier I need to strip the numbers out of the letters so I can set a target, i.e.,

set(['A', 'B', 'C'])

What I need first to do is to create an output with stripped headers, such that the new csv file should read:

A, B, B, B, C, C, C
0.2,0.456,0.7,1.01,0.91,0.11,0.31

Because the files which I have are pretty massive, I want from my function to navigate  through the columns of large numbers and strip their headers from the numbers. May be the code will act like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pnda
#from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge, Lasso
import string
import csv
import os

# Please don't pay attention to the first part of the code, it is just to load the file 

def get_file_path(filename):
    drkt = os.getcwd()
    file_path = os.path.join(drkt,filename)

    return file_path
    file_path = get_file_path('testing.csv')


def read_csv(file_path):
    data_file = open(file_path, 'rU')
    reader = csv.reader(data_file)
    headers_=reader.next()
print headers_ # Just to see the lines
```

This is for sure a very primitive code but I just want to demonstrate the point where I got stuck. I basically would like to use "strip("0123456789=,")" for the header 'row' only but I don't know how to reach that point. I managed to strip the headers but I find my code pull out and strip the entire column which is not what I want, I namely would like to strip the first row in each csv date file.

Please accept my apologies if my message is long or if I failed to explain my point well.

Look forward to hear from your side

Comment: Why not just call `strip` on `headers_`? If you're looping through the rows, handle the headers outside that loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @whereswalden suggested, you're almost there

```
import csv

def read_csv(file_path):
    data_file = open(file_path, 'rU')
    reader = csv.reader(data_file)
    headers_=reader.next()
    print headers_ # ['A', ' B1', ' B2', ' B3', ' C1', ' C2', ' C3']

    # Process headers outside of loop
    headers_ = [col.strip("0123456789=,") for col in headers_]
    print headers_ # ['A', ' B', ' B', ' B', ' C', ' C', ' C']

    for row in reader:
        # do what you want with the data rows
```

Comment: This code dose the job beautifully. Thank you very much Tony, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about striping them out using regex ?

This one will remove all the integers from the headers.

```
import re
col = "A2"

re.sub(r"\d","",col)
```

***output***

```
A
```

In your case

```
headers_=reader.next()
headers_ = [re.sub(r"\d","",col) for col in headers_]
# do something with headers_
```

Comment: Thank you Mevin, I appreciate the time you took to reply to my post. I find the answer by Tony (above) pretty neat and practical, it does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

I do not completely understand what you are asking but are you looking for a function like this?

```
 def remove_numbers(l):
     #Create string to use for output
     output = "";
     #loop through the input string
     for x in l:
        #Test to see what characters are NOT digits
         if not x.isdigit():
            #If it isn't a digit add it to the output string
            output += x
    #Return the output string
    return output
```

This function takes a string as an input and removes the characters that are digits. Running this input `A, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3` you get this output `'A, B, B, B, C, C, C'`. I suppose you could run this before you did other processing.

Edit: Regular expressions could also be used to accomplish this goal

Comment: Many thanks for the time you took to reply, much appreciated. I used the answer by Tony (first one) which does it beautifully.